# How should ffmpeg support fixed framerate encoding

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, dxgi

I use DXGI to capture desktop, and encode the captured frame to h264 stream.
Now the captured video stream's framerte is 25 fps, and I want the result h264 stream's frame is 60 fps.
I found that even if I set the h264 encoder's framerate to be 60fps, but the result isn't expected.
So what should I do, then ffmpeg would insert frames automatically?

Comment: "The captured video stream is 25 fps". What prevents you from changing that? Whayt have you tried? What doesn't work, what error do you get? Please provide some minimal reproducible sample code https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: ffmpeg can not produce missing frames from the thin air. While it is possible to perform some advanced frame rate interpolation (which still won't produce genuine 60 fps video) it is not implemented in ffmpeg.